# How can I get all cities within a given radius of a given city from the HERE API?

Tags: here-api

I need to be able to give a City/State or Postal Code and an Integer for the radius and return all cities/postal codes within the given radius using HERE but the Documentation seems to be unclear.

`https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxxx`

The return is:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">
  <Details>invalid credentials for xxxxxxx</Details>
</ns2:Error>
```

But when I use

`https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxxx`

I get data back.

It is worth mentioning I am on the Freemium Package for the REST API

So first why can't I get data back from the Reverse Geo Code API?

And what is the appropriate string to accomplish the above?

**Update:**

Leaving the rest here in case someone else runs into this. To use Reverse Geo Code the API Route is actually

`https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json`

Though I still need some help on how to get the Radius Data

**Update 2:**

`https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=x&app_code=x&level=city&mode=retrieveAreas&prox=52.5309,13.3847,80467.2`

Returns:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2019-04-27T17:47:41.043+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "Distance": 0,
            "Direction": 0,
            "MatchLevel": "district",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "State": 1,
              "County": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "District": 1,
              "PostalCode": 1
            },
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_0ES-GaH3lZzJCuLQBrdw7C",
              "LocationType": "point",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 52.5309,
                "Longitude": 13.3847
              },
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 52.54063,
                  "Longitude": 13.36566
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 52.50407,
                  "Longitude": 13.42964
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "Mitte, Berlin, Deutschland",
                "Country": "DEU",
                "State": "Berlin",
                "County": "Berlin",
                "City": "Berlin",
                "District": "Mitte",
                "PostalCode": "10178",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Deutschland",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Berlin",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Berlin",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "MapReference": {
                "ReferenceId": "53500282",
                "SideOfStreet": "neither",
                "CountryId": "20147700",
                "StateId": "20187401",
                "CountyId": "20187402",
                "CityId": "20187403",
                "DistrictId": "20187417"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The documentation says to put in coordinates and a radius, that's 50 miles, so not sure why I am only receiving 1 city, Berlin, in the response.

**Update 3:**

`https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json?app_id=x&app_code=x&level=city&mode=retrieveAreas&prox=60.5544,-151.2583,80000`

Tried with `multi-reversegeocode`

Return is: `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get cities in a proximity radius

Use the **Reverse Geocode** endpoint with the following parameters

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?
prox=52.5309,13.3847,80500   /* Note: 80.5 km around Berlin */
&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE
&mode=retrieveAreas
&level=city
&gen=9
```

In short, your example in "Update 2" is correct, besides that it is missing the `gen` query parameter. Indeed, as per the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html), the query parameter `level` is valid only in combination with `gen=2` or higher.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know if this counts as multiple "transactions" or one @Michael P. Bazos

Comment: I did not personally track that, but it shouldn't be more than one transaction, according to https://developer.here.com/faqs#licensing-terms (point 2)