# HERE maps API v7 - get all cities in radius

Tags: here-api

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883181/how-can-i-get-all-cities-within-a-given-radius-of-a-given-city-from-the-here-api) question, but it uses API v6 - and things changed significantly in v7.

So according to the [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html), the way to do it is by using the `/browse` endpoint. So my query is:

```
https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?
at=28.233981,-82.444708
&categories=900-9100-0000
&in=circle:28.233981,-82.444708;r=20000
&apiKey=<my-key>
```

According to [this guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/category-900-areas-buildings.html), 900-9100-0000 is a category for any city, town, or village. Nevertheless, the query returns an empty array.

How do I get the towns in a circle?

**Update**: if I remove the `in` parameter, the result still returns empty :/

Comment: Can you please fix the "this guide" link so I can understand your question better and see if I can help you? At the moment, it is broken.

Comment: Hi. Sorry it took long to get back here. I will check with our dev team, because this is strange. The category works if you add the "!" at the start, and it ignores cities in the results, but if you do the opposite (which you are doing) it is empty like you say.

Comment: please do. It's a really weird unexpected behavior